# Why messages printed after closing main window in Qt C++?

Tags: c++, qt, output

With this code

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <QDir>
#include <QTextStream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTextStream out(stdout);
    out << QDir::currentPath();
    std::cout << "Why is that?";

    MainWindow mainWindow;
    mainWindow.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Both messages printed only after closing Main Window of my app, why is this?
I tried to debug, debugger thinks that he done with this line, but I see no messages.

Comment: Flush the streams.

Comment: Or output to std::err, there should be no buffering there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`extern std::ostream cout;` is buffered, so it may choose when to flush its buffer to `stdout`. In your case, it is doing it when your program is terminating.

You can tell `std::ostream` to flush using std::flush, as such:

```
std::cout << "Why is that?" << std::flush;
```